# How to rename files to match parent folder's name and add a incremental number with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a usb drive with many pictures (and in many folders), and I am trying to find a way to name them after the folder they are in + a number added to it so that I won't have duplicate file names.

I have tried to search here for how to do that ↑, but I only found out how to rename files fo ADD the parent folder name instead of replacing it, and I also found out how to add a number to the file name, but I was unable to connect anything together.

Instead of having it like this

```
2healthbars/
picture A.jpg
picture B.jpg
picture C.jpg
picture D.jpg
```

I want it to be like this:

```
2healthbars/
2healthbars-1.jpg
2healthbars-2.jpg
2healthbars-3.jpg
2healthbars-4.jpg
```

Comment: Can you post whatever you've tried till now? Have you made any progress?

Comment: I haven't made much progress yet, but I _did_ manage to _add_ folder name(s) to the image file names, so that's something.

Comment: So right now you have something like "Folder A - picture A.jpg"?

Comment: eh, more like "folderApictureA.jpg" for now but yes.

Comment: what is your folder **actually** named as? Can you edit your question and post output of tree command?